# Serving static files via nginx instead of express

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I know there are quite a few threads on this topic, but unfortunately none of them helped me so far. I had an express application and served my static files like this:

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: 86400000 }));
```

Now I'm using nginx aswell and wanted to serve my static content only via nginx, so I commented the line above and added the following to my `sites-enabled/default` nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    // certificate, server_Name

    location ~^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
       root /path/to/my/project/public/;
       access_log off;
       expires 24h;
     }
}

location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
}
```

From what I've read so far the first location block should handle the serving of static files (all my static files are located under `public`). But when I start my application like this I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Only once I add the express config from above my site works.

How can I serve static content via nginx correctly?
Does anyone have some guidance on what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure, do you get the same error if you create a different server block?

Comment: Let *location / {}* be the nested part of *server* block first

Comment: I get the same error with different server block and with the `locatio /` before the static file handling block